# How to use React-datepicker with custom data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am trying to make a custom react-datepicker but my code is not working correctly.

```
const [filterDateFrom, setFilterDateFrom] = useState("");
const [filterDateTo, setFilterDateTo] = useState("");
const [startDate, endDate] = filterDateFrom && filterDateTo;
```

then I have a function to pull the date and my return is something like:

```
<div>
  <DatePicker
   filterDateFrom={true}
   filterDateTo={true}
   startDate={startDate}
   endDate={endDate}
   onChange={(update) => {
   setFilterDateFrom(update) && setFilterDateTo(update)
   }}
   withPortal
   />
 </div>
```

But when I select the dates the code breaks.

The DatePicker on the official documentation looks like this:

```
<DatePicker
      selectsRange={true}
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      onChange={(update) => {
        setDateRange(update);
      }}
    />
```

Any ideas?

Here is a snippet from my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Period From": "2021-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Period To": "2021-02-27T23:00:00.000Z",
  }
]
```

Update on my Code:

```
const [filterDateFrom, setFilterDateFrom] = useState(new Date());
const [filterDateTo, setFilterDateTo] = useState(null);

  const onChange = (dates) => {
    console.log(dates);
    const [start, end] = dates;
    setFilterDateFrom(start);
    setFilterDateTo(end);
  };
```

And then Im applying a filter that looks like this:

```
const displaySongs = songs
.filter((song) => {
keepSong &&=
        filterDateFrom === "" || filterDateTo === "" ||
        song["Period From"]?.toLowerCase().includes(filterDateFrom.toLowerCase() || song["Period To"]?.toLowerCase().includes(filterDateTo.toLowerCase()));

      return keepSong;
    })
    .map((song) => {
      return (
        <tr className="font-medium bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">

          ... I'm displaying more data here

          <td className="py-2 px-4 text-left">{song["Track Title"]}</td>
          ... and here.
        </tr>
      );
    });

return (
    <div className="flex-1 px-10">
      <div className="flex gap-4">
        <div className="flex sticky top-0 justify-between items-center my-10 gap-4 shadow-md rounded-md p-6 bg-slate-900">
      <div>
      <DatePicker
        selected={filterDateFrom}
        onChange={onChange}
        startDate={filterDateFrom}
        endDate={filterDateTo}
        selectsRange

      />
      </div>

      <table className="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 shadow-md rounded">
        <thead className="text-gray-700 uppercase bg-slate-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          <tr>
            <th className="py-2 px-4 text-left">Track Title</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{displaySongs}</tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
```

Im getting this error in my console:

```
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught TypeError: filterDateFrom.toLowerCase is not a function
```

Comment: What's error poped?

Comment: I'm trying to pass some dates from my database using some values like 'Period From' and 'Period To'. The error is: react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught TypeError: filterDateFrom.toLowerCase is not a function. Not so sure how to add the values into the <DatePicker>

Comment: I just read the doc of react-datepicker, it doesn't seems it has filterDateFrom, filterDateTo startDate endDate properties.  What do you try to achieve?

Comment: trying to add an state to pull my data from the database.

Comment: gotta be specific, what data from database. are you not just select a date, but want to set a range? or you need to select date picker field for "from" date and "to" date?

Comment: @nate-cheng I just updated the question with an snippet of my JSON file, the one Im trying to pull.

Comment: What do you need for from and to? I mean its a range for datepicker or you want to select two dates for two fields.

Comment: @nate-cheng trying to filter the date range from my database

Comment: Are you trying to set a min-max date so that the user cannot select beyond that or trying to implement a date range?

Comment: @prabhakaran I'm trying to select a date range so when I will filter I will get the data from my database table

Comment: So you want a custom date range component, and on selecting the date range the data will be fetched. Am I correct?

Comment: @Prabhakaran that's correct :)

Comment: @nate-cheng thank you so much for your time and help. I just added an update of the code on my question and the error I'm getting on my console.

Comment: Can you post the sample song data?

Comment: @Prabhakaran
 its there :)

Comment: @stewieGriffin filterDateFrom and  filterDateTo are not string, it's a date type

Comment: @nate-cheng do I need to convert it into a string? I have even used a date picker before :/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set this way.

```
function App() {
  const [filterDateFrom, setFilterDateFrom] = useState(new Date());
  const [filterDateTo, setFilterDateTo] = useState(null);

  const onChange = (dates) => {
    const [start, end] = dates;
    setFilterDateFrom(start);
    setFilterDateTo(end);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatePicker
        selected={filterDateFrom}
        onChange={onChange}
        startDate={filterDateFrom}
        endDate={filterDateTo}
        selectsRange
        inline
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```